# Using Spartacus, Add to cart service is throwing error : "Required String parameter 'product' is not present"

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Following are the details of the service call:

Request URL: https://localhost:9002/rest/v2/electronics-spa/users/current/carts/00003001/entries?code=816802&qty=1&lang=en&curr=JPY

Response:
Status Code: 400
{
   "errors" : [ {
      "message" : "Required String parameter 'product' is not present",
      "type" : "MissingServletRequestParameterError"
   } ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the *b2boccaddon* extension included in your SAP Commerce instance?  In current versions of SAP Commerce, that extension overrides/changes some of the B2C OCC calls in a way that is not compatible with standard Spartacus.

For example *B2BCartsController.addCartEntry()* expects a parameter *product* for the product code.  Whereas the B2C version *CartsController.addCartEntry()* expects a parameter *code* for a product code.  The standard Spartacus implementation is written to work with the B2C version rather than the B2B version.

To make use of the *b2boccaddon* you would need to customise the OCC calls made from within Spartacus

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you further give some more information on how to customise the OCC calls made from within Spartacus, so that I can follow the same and make it working?

Comment: For Spartacus connectivity to the backend, see the Connector Logic section in https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/connecting-to-other-systems/ - you would need to adapt the existing logic for OCC connections (see OccCartEntryAdaptor).

Alternatively you could create your own OCC AddOn on the SAP Commerce side. See Creating an AddOn for OCC Web Services: https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/1905/en-US/8b96a80f8669101482d4f3c1e27b4eb6.html

Answer (score 0):

@Puja, Spartacus is using a data binding architecture, which allows you to hook into various layers. You can read more about it at https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/connecting-to-other-systems/. You could configure standard OCC endpoints or adapt alternative backend systems.

If you use a standard setup, you should be able to use standard OCC endpoints, but the backend setup might be wrong. Neils suggestion could be the one that is blocking you.

Comment: I don't have the b2boccaddon added in the configuration file. But still having the same issue.

Comment: Ok, but the error you have is very much the same.  I suggest you look at any occ addons you have installed in Commerce, both custom/standard & see if any are adapting the behaviour of that Add Cart Entry call.  The error suggests that something has changed the parameters that the backend expects for this call